# Android use java script to highlight text in webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using webview to render html file and i used java script to highlight (Hello) word in html

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity{
WebView myWebView;
TextView myResult;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myResult = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.myResult);

    myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
   String txt="Hello";
   myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var text='"+ txt+ "';if (window.find) {document.designMode ='on';var sel = window.getSelection();sel.collapse(document.body, 0);while (window.find(text)) { document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, 'red');sel.collapseToEnd();}document.designMode = 'off';} else if (document.body.createTextRange) { var textRange = document.body.createTextRange(); while (textRange.findText(text)) {textRange.execCommand('BackColor', false, 'red'); textRange.collapse(false);}}");
   myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptHandler(this), "MyHandler"); 
  }
```

and this my html

```
  <html>
   <head>
   </head>
  <body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
   </body>
   </html>
```

this code is run good in debug mode i mean that it already highlight (hello) but in running mode it did not why???????????
i do not know what it mean that running good in debug mode but not in running mode?